# Mysql Event Scheduler precisa super privileges

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database-first

Bom dia, eu tenho um alojamento de um website numa empresa, criei um sistema muito simples que atraves de um evento que corre de um determinado tempo em um determinado tempo e faz alterações nos elementos da base de dados (neste caso altera o campo "estado" sempre que a data de expiração foi ultrapassada), porém auando clico no butao de `Event Shedule Status` para on ele da-me um `erro 1227` que diz que eu nao tenho `super previlleges`. E possivel manter activar sem ter esse previlegios? existe alguma forma de implementar um sistema do genero sem necessitar desses previlegios? ou tenho de contactar a empresa?
p.s: Isto é comum ou trata-se de algum problema desta empresa de alojamento?
Peço desculpa pela ignorância  em alojamentos, mas não tenho muita experiência com isto.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa ter no minimo o privilégio para executar o evento neste schema, para isso teria que rodar o comando para dar o privilégio assim:

```
GRANT EVENT ON myschema.* TO jon@ghidora;
```

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-privileges.html